# NestedScrollView not scrolling in recyclerView generated data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I'm using a NestedScrollView in a CardView that's generated in a RecyclerView. I can't get the scrolling to work - there seems to be sporadic moments when I can scroll through the list in the top item but no other scrolls seem to work. Cheers!

[image]

This is the layout of the cardView that's generated in the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/checkout_relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/merchantPurchase"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkoutCard"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/checkoutCard"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:contentPadding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_goneMarginLeft="5dp"
    app:layout_goneMarginRight="5dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCentre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="Test2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.7"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/extraContainer"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/extraContainer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="Test3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/otherContainer"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/otherContainer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:text="Test1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.444"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/priceContainer"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/priceContainer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/extraContainer"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/priceContainer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priceContainer"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/itemTitle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/otherContainer"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/extraContainer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.512" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/otherContainer"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="19dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="258dp">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView45"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView44"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView43"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Then, my abridged code for MainActivity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checkout_home);

    cardPurchasesDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < productsForPurchase.length; i++) {
        cardPurchasesDataSet.add(productsForPurchase[i]);
    }
    card_totalPrice = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalPriceData.length; i++) {
        card_totalPrice.add(totalPriceData[i]);
    }
    card_extras = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < extrasData.length; i++) {
        card_extras.add(extrasData[i]);
    }
    card_more = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < moreData.length; i++) {
        card_more.add(moreData[i]);
    }
    merchants = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < merchantsData.length; i++) {
        merchants.add(merchantsData[i]);
    }

    card_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    card_layoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    card_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(card_layoutManger);
    card_adapter = new checkout_card_Adapter(cardPurchasesDataSet, card_totalPrice, card_extras, card_more, merchants);
    card_recyclerView.setAdapter(card_adapter);
}
```

**UPDATE 01: Added mainActivity layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="551dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
```

**Adapter**

```
public class Checkout_Card_Adapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Checkout_Card_Adapter.ViewHolder>{
private ArrayList<String> titleOfPurchase;
private ArrayList<String> priceOfPurchase;
private ArrayList<String> extrasOfPurchase;
private ArrayList<String> moreOfPurchase;
private ArrayList<String> merchantOfPurchase;

public Checkout_Card_Adapter(ArrayList<String> titleOfPurchase, ArrayList<String> priceOfPurchase, ArrayList<String> extrasOfPurchase, ArrayList<String> moreOfPurchase, ArrayList<String> merchantOfPurchase) {
    this.titleOfPurchase = titleOfPurchase;
    this.priceOfPurchase = priceOfPurchase;
    this.extrasOfPurchase = extrasOfPurchase;
    this.moreOfPurchase = moreOfPurchase;
    this.merchantOfPurchase = merchantOfPurchase;
}

public interface VenueAdapterInterface {
    void onVenueButtonClick(int position);
}

@Override
public Checkout_Card_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checkout_scrollable_card, viewGroup, false);
    Checkout_Card_Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new Checkout_Card_Adapter.ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Checkout_Card_Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titleOfPurchase.get(position));
    viewHolder.itemPrice.setText(priceOfPurchase.get(position));
    viewHolder.itemExtras.setText(extrasOfPurchase.get(position));
    viewHolder.itemMore.setText(moreOfPurchase.get(position));
    viewHolder.merchant.setText(merchantOfPurchase.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return titleOfPurchase.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageButton itemImage;
    public TextView itemTitle;
    public TextView itemPrice;
    public TextView itemExtras;
    public TextView itemMore;
    public TextView merchant;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        itemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceContainer);
        itemExtras = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.extraContainer);
        itemMore = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.otherContainer);
        merchant = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.merchantPurchase);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where are you using recyclerview in your layout?

Comment: Cheers for your response @Zeeshan just added the mainActivity code then

Comment: remove this android:overScrollMode="never"

Comment: Adds the blue overscroll view at the top and bottom of the screen. But doesn't affect the nested scroll in the card.

Comment: Please post you adapter class here

Comment: Added adapter class

Comment: Everything seems fine here, Can you post your project on github, so I can look deep into it]

Comment: Sure, just added a photo of the layout and the scrollView's position within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your screen shot how do you expect it to scroll the inner view while it showing all the views? it will only scroll on small devices where your all textview won't be able to display. Can you please post a proper screenshot of this view from app.

Comment: It's not showing all the views - I've added five and it only shows those 3, it just appears to show only them because there's no visible text from the others.

Comment: How do you expect it to display five values when you just mentioned 3 in you xml?

Comment: Ah apologies, I've been editing it since. Even with 5 it still doesn't work.

Comment: try using scrollview rather than nestedscrollview, It should work

Comment: Switched between both and having the same result. I think it could be to do with the recyclerview's onScrollListener. I disabled this but didn't have any luck. As the reyclerview is a more enhanced version of the scrollview I'm assuming the trouble is coming from the two scroll views demanding onScrollListeners but only one being able to receive. I can see that the RecyclerView is responding to scrolling when I add the overScrollMode = "true"

Comment: I seen your screenshot, what exactly do you want? to scroll the left number line of each view?

Comment: The list of numbers on the far left. I can't scroll that list.

Comment: Can you share the data? You want to populate in one view